# What is an "improbability field"

Tags: quantum-field-theory

I believe that Star Trek has advisors so that their science has at least a tenuous theoretical basis.  The latest episode is based on interacting with an "improbability field". Is this just gibberish or is there some conceptual basis in quantum field theory?  The only reference I can find is in [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08WZH8PK8) that says `which entails the process that allows for the development of Multidimensional Geometry through its use of Vibrations, the actual nature of Numbers and Math as a whole, the formation of Particles and Fields, and how Quantum Entanglement is instrumental to that`

Comment: I googled Technobabble. This [collection of Star Trek clips](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=technobabble#fpstate=ive&vld=cid:2a9268ac,vid:naXLxNX4UZc) was one of the top hits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably gibberish, but seems like the basic premise might be that

1. any quantum object can quantum tunnel through a barrier, with a vanishingly low probability, and/or
2. the wavefunction of the spatial location of a quantum object trails off exponentially from a central region, but never actually reaches zero.  So in theory an electron in a lab has some vanishingly small probability of being detected on Mars.

The Star Trek plot device may be based on the idea of taking these quantum properties and somehow altering the probability of these tunneling or teleporting events from "vanishingly improbable" to "probable," in order to achieve faster-than-light travel of macroscopic objects like star ships.

The *Hitchhiker's Guide* series has a similar device called the Infinite Improbability Drive.

Comment: Thanks. In the show it was being tested to send messages only, not material objects.  Quite different from Hitchhiker - which is obviously not scientifically based.

Comment: I think in principle any device that can transmit a message can transmit matter, because an object could be scanned to the molecular level, and that information transmitted to a 3D printer on the other side to recreate it. Excluding things like living creatures and consciousness which are mysteries to us at present...

Comment: Please try to avoid answering questions that are largely nonsense like this.

Comment: @KyleKanos I didn't ask if the theory was true. But having a deep interest in quantum field theory, I wanted to know if there was any basis at all in this concept. This is exactly the kind of thing the stock exchange should be used for. To provide answers that I can't find elsewhere.

Comment: @foolishmuse your question is obviously nonsense. If a quick Google search (i.e., part of the [sufficient prior research](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5779/25301)) comes up empty w.r.t. academic instances (e.g., textbooks), it's probably not real. Asking about such nonsense on SE sites wastes peoples time. You could ask in [chat], which probably wouldn't waste as much time.